# How to check if one package out of a few is not installed

Tags: fedora, dnf

How does one check whether a package is installed in Fedora?

Say I have `curl ca-certificates gnupg2 lldb python3-minimal gcc libc6-dev` and I want to check in `if` whether any of these is not installed.

The only thing I could come up with so far was calling `dnf list installed` and manually comparing the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
rpm -q curl
```

will return with a null status (success) if a package named `curl` is installed, and with a failure return code if not; e.g.

```bash
rpm -q curl > /dev/null || printf "curl not installed\n"
rpm -q gnupg2 > /dev/null && printf "gnupg2 installed\n"
if rpm -q gcc > /dev/null ; then
  ;
else
  printf "Missing GCC; will not be able to compile naught from nothing!\n"
fi
```

works well.

A more versatile approach is to ask `dnf repoquery --installed`; e.g. `dnf repoquery --installed --whatprovides python3` could be used to detect whichever package contains a python3. However, you'll need to check the output, through something like `if [ -z "$(dnf repoquery --installed --whatprovides python3)" ]`. The advantage lies in being able to ask whether there's some package that installed a `/usr/bin/foo` (`dnf repoquery --installed -f /usr/bin/foo`) or some pkg-config for some library (`dnf repoquery --installed --whatprovides "pkgconfig(libcurl)"`), without having to keep knowledge of which package these things are in.